# Why would square root of 1 equals 1 returns false in java?

Tags: java, stream, square-root

```
public static boolean checkSquare(int i){
    return IntStream
            .rangeClosed(1, i/2)
            .anyMatch(x -> Math.sqrt(x) == i);
}
```

When I enter 1 as an user input, it return false. I don't understand why square root of 1 is not equals to 1. Can anyone tell me is my code correct?

Comment: Further reading: [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: Do *not* change an existing question to something entirely else, please.

Answer (score 4):

If your user input is assigned your `i` variable, it's clear why

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i/2).anyMatch(x -> Math.sqrt(x) == i);
```

returns `false` when `i==1`, since `1/2 == 0`, so `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 0)` is an empty stream.

Change your method to:

```
public static boolean checkSquare(int i){
    return IntStream
            .rangeClosed(1, i)
            .anyMatch(x -> Math.sqrt(x) == i);
}
```

or, if you really want to keep the optimization of halving the size of the `IntStream`:

```
public static boolean checkSquare(int i) {
    return IntStream
            .rangeClosed(1, Math.max(1,i/2))
            .anyMatch(x -> Math.sqrt(x) == i);
}
```

Comment: Now i understand my mistake. Thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: @SendHelpPls if an answer really solves your question, mark it as answer.